# How to simplify my imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

In my project each class is a file and my directory structure like this:

```
main.py
myGui/
    __init__.py (empty)
    ClassA.py
    ClassB.py
```

To use my classes In main.py I need import with:

```
from myGui.ClassA import ClassA
from myGui.ClassB import ClassB
```

How to import with:

```
from myGui import ClassA, ClassB
```

Comment: Do you really need for `ClassA` and `ClassB` to be separate module? If you're often going to be using them both at the same time, perhaps their definitions should be in the same file. Unlike some other programming languages (e.g. Java), Python doesn't require each class to be its own file.

Comment: This is just a example. In my project (not finished), I have 21 classes and two packages.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest following the PEP 8 naming convention and giving your modules names in lowercase (e.g. `class_a`) and only using capitolized names (e.g. `ClassA`) for the classes within them. This way you won't get confused about what name refers to what kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this into your `__init__.py`

```
from .ClassA import ClassA
from .ClassB import ClassB
```

And then import them like you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added them to your __ init__.py,

```
from . import ClassA, ClassB
```

Should work.